# Indentation based color coded background in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm making heavy use of languages with syntactic whitespace (LiveScript, Emblem, Stylus, YAML)

Is there a way to configure the backgrounds of indentation?

I read that I could color these tiny indentation lines, but this isn't enough.

Here a mock-up of what I'm thinking about:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking for this too, and I was thinking that simply changing the background color of the indented area based on how many lines there are would be great. I'm not sure how to do that, but I did find a similar solution here:

https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/issues/153

That will get you lines that look like this: [image: image of colored indentation]

Specifically, that page says:

```
Just add these settings to Monokai Soda.tmTheme file in settings dictionary, displayed in screenshot

<key>guide</key>
<string>#92003b</string>
<key>activeGuide</key>
<string>#7fb11b</string>
<key>stackGuide</key>
<string>#635f2d</string>
```

Another user at the above page says the following:

```
Just wanted to point out to others, that you'll need to enable "draw_active", in user prefs, like so:

"indent_guide_options":
[
    "draw_normal",
    "draw_active"
],
```

They also reference this page in the above link:
http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-indentation-guide-lines/

These options look like they will help somewhat, but they aren't an exact answer to your question. I would definitely like to see something like what you mention.